# Bootstrap 3.3.0 + Typeahead inside form-control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with the following packages:

- Typeahead.js
- Typeahead.js for MVC 5
- typeahead.js-bootstrap.css
- Bootstrap (3.3.0)

I'm having trouble rendering the autocomplete input text correctly in the page (below the other input  and aligned).

**HTML**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Test</label>
            <input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="test">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var engine = new Bloodhound({
     datumTokenizer: function (d) { return d.value; },
     queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
     local: [{ value: 'dog animal' }, { value: 'pig animal' }, { value: 'moose animal' }, { value: 'bird ' }]
 });

 engine.initialize();

 $('#search').typeahead(null, {
     name: 'animals',
     source: engine.ttAdapter()
 })
</script>
```

**PAGE**

[image: Page Rendering]

Comment: I test your code here: http://www.bootply.com/021DbnZ2mP and i was not able the reproduce the problem you describe.